# Read /proc/<pid>/fd/<fd> without full root access

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, root, linux-capabilities

I have a program (https://github.com/raboof/connbeat) that relies on `/proc/[pid]/fd/*` to find processes given a (networking) inode.

`/proc/[pid]/fd` can only be read by root, but I'd like to drop privileges as much as possible for security.

Is there some way I could (efficiently) get to the relationship between processes and inodes without requiring full root rights? Perhaps some syscall that I can selectively give access to using capabilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to read fd's of all the processes you need:

- CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH - for access to /proc/[pid]/fd
- CAP_SYS_PTRACE - to read symlinks under /proc/[pid]/fd/*

You can restrict your program to just these two capabilities. Then you can access the information in question using ordinary API calls like `readdir()` or `readlink()` or whatever else you prefer.

For a broader description of these two capabilities please refer to [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)